# How to manage redux selector when two branches of state tree have same selector name?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

For example, assume that we have a sliced state called `game`. Under the `game` we have two entities, `enemies` and `items`. Each entity has x coordinate to record its position. The state tree looks like this:

```
{
  game: {
    enemies: {
      allEnemies: [
        {
          id: 1,
          x: 100,
        },
        {
          id: 3,  
          x: 300,
        }
      ],
      allEnemiesById: [1, 3],
    },
    items: {
      allItems: [
        {
          id: 2,
          x: 200,
        },
        {
          id: 7,
          x: 500,
        }
      ],
      allItemsById: [2, 7],
    }
  }
}
```

Of course the `enemy` entity and `item` entity will have other different properties. Also there are other logics in `game` reducer so I can't simply remove it.

Now, in the `game` reducer, we have two selectors to get the visible enemies and items respectively. They delegate the selector function in `enemies` and `items` since I don't want to make `game` know the state tree detail of `enemies` and `items`:

`reducers/game.js`

```
import { enemies, selector1 } from './enemies.js';
import { items, selector2 } from './items.js';
const getVisibleEnemies = (state) => selector1(state.enemies)
const getVisibleItems = (state) => selector2(state.items)
```

But now the problem is: what should be the name of `selector1` and `selector2`? I thought about some solutions but I'm not quite satisfied:

(1) `getVisibleEntities`: but we can't have two same function name in `game`;

(2) `getVisibleXXX`: but that's as same as the selector name in `game`.

(3) Just call the selector of `enemies` and `items` directly in client code e.g.(`getVisibleEnemies(state.game.enemies)` in `mapStateToProps`): But now the caller has to know the deep shape of state tree, once the state tree changes it will be painful to change all of them.

(4) bind the selector in the reducer function, for example:

`reducers/enemies.js`
    export const getVisibleEntities(state) => {
      // implementation of getVisibleEntities for enemies
    }

```
export const enemies = (state = initialState, action) {
  // main reducer of enemies
}
enemies.getVisibleEntities = getVisibleEntities
```

`reducers/items.js`
    export const getVisibleEntities(state) => {
      // implementation of getVisibleEntities for items
    }

```
export const items = (state = initialState, action) {
  // main reducer of items
}
items.getVisibleEntities = getVisibleEntities
```

`reducers/game.js`

```
export const getVisibleEnemies = (state) => enemies.getVisibleEntities(state.enemies)
export const getVisibleItems = (state) => items.getVisibleEntities(state.enemies)
```

But I'm not sure if it's a good idea to set selector as property on state reducer.

(5) give it a slightly different name e.g. `getVisibleEnemies` in `game.js` and `getVisibleEnemiesImpl` in `enemies.js`: It's fine but I'm wondering there should be better way to handle this.

So what will you do?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should go with option (3) but:

- Your selector shoud be a function of the entire Redux store state
- This way your containers (smart components) don't have to know the deep shape of your state tree